# sorting and grouping of an obj array

Tags: c++

Imagine this as an object array. An object consist of a type, and score.
 Suppose i need to sort them accordingly, to either type a or b, giving a the priority, followed by score from 0 -100 in desc order.

```
 [0]   [1]   [2]   [3]    [4]     [5]    [6]
----------------------------------------------
|a   | b   | a   |   a |    b  |    b  |  a  |
|50  | 90  | 30  |   80|    20 |   30  |  60 |
----------------------------------------------
```

after sorting, it will be something like this.

```
[0]   [1]   [2]   [3]    [4]     [5]    [6]
----------------------------------------------
| a  | a   | a   |   a |   b   |    b  |  b  |
| 80 | 60  | 50  | 30  |  90   |  30   | 20  |
----------------------------------------------
```

only allowed to use if else statement, loops e.g(for, do while, while), with the minimal amount of codes. The only i thought of is sort the array by grouping a together, followed by doing sorting in desc ordered. Using nested for loop, with an if else statement

```
char first, second;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{ 
  first = array[i].getType();
  for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        second = array[j].getType();
        if ((first.compare('a') == 0) && (second.compare('a') != 0) ||
              (first.compare('a') != 0)  && (second.compare('a') == 0))
        {
             Obj temp = array[i];
             array[i] = array[j];
     array[j] = temp; 
         }
     }
 }
```

followed by a sort in desc order. I'm sure there is a better solution out there. any one can share on how you can solve this?

Comment: Why can't you use the Standard Library? It's there for a reason.

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblesort and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort for the pseudocode for some sorting algorithms.  Bubble sort is easier, quick sort is better.

Comment: `std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [](const Object& l, const Object& r){ return l.type == r.type ? l.score < r.score : l.type < r.type;});`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest way in my opinion is to define a comparison operator for your type.

```
struct object
{
  char type;
  int score;
}

bool operator<(object const& l, object const& r)
{
  return (l.type == r.type) ? l.score < r.score : r.type < l.type;
}
```

You can use this with the `std::sort` algorithm from STL:

```
vector<object> objs;
std::sort(objs.begin(), objs.end());
```

Works the same with C-style arrays.

If you are not allowed to use `std::sort` (as in some homework) then you can implement any sorting algorithm (bubblesort, quicksort, etc.) and simply compare two `object`s with operator <.

```
// dummy example
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
   {
      auto second = objs[j];
      if(!(objs[i] < objs[j]))
         std::swap(objs[i], objs[j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: It rarely (possibly never) makes sense to define an `operator<` for a type without defining the other 5 comparison operators. If the type _should_ be comparable define all 6, otherwise if this is just for sorting, which in this case it is, create a comparator for `sort` instead of muddying what you can do with the type, inconsistently.